# Need to count entries

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am looking to make it so that each item in a list has a column that shows how many total items there are in that list that share the same value in a column as that list item. If that makes sense. To elaborate more, I need to keep count of how many times someones name is put in a list it must also be able to do this with names that have not been determined ahead of time. I though that there maybe a way to do this with a calculated column, something like =(Value(['Column Name"]),"Total" but I am not seeing anything in the Syntax that might work. Is it even possible to calculate data from all items in a list?

Comment: You can not use calculation column for calculated vertical column. calculation column only used to calculated value from same row. I think group by may be help you. You can do group by name and display count

Comment: This is definitely helpful for viewing them. My reason behind wanting to display these numbers in a column is so that I can have flows trigger to send alerts when thresholds are met.

Comment: But for that you can't use calculated column. You can write logic on flow when Item added to list do filter by Name or any column and check count. If count is match with threshold then send alerts